# How to monitor all exceptions occuring on behalf of the CLR?

Tags: .net, exception, logging, clr

I want to monitor all exceptions that are occurring on a server. The server runs various apps and websites. I am not the writer of these apps and websites and web services. Is there any way I can write an application that will monitor the managed code that runs on the system and log all the un-handled exceptions that occur on the system. I was thinking this should be possible because the OS is the one who generates exceptions. So is it possible for me to log all exceptions that are generated by the OS.

Answer (score 0):

One could inspect all process, inspect all appdomains with mscoree.CorRuntimeHostClass and then bind to all the unhandled exception event handlers (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx).

An other option is to use al the debug api's. 
There is however Avicode, a product of microsoft product which does that (and is/will be part of scom).